# Parse Cloud: Send Push to a single user

Tags: parse-platform, cloud, push, where-clause

I'm using Parse and I can't make this method to work.

The idea is to send push to a single user with an already known user identifier from any platform within 'Cloud code'.

Queries I've tried without push being delivered to that user (actually no push was delivered to any user)

- PFInstallation through the user pointer:

  `var targetUser = new Parse.User();`

  `targetUser.id = userID;`

  `var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);`

  `query.equalTo('user', targetUser);`
- Query in PFUser itself

  `var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);`

  `query.equalTo('objectId', userID);`

Full code for the method:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendPushContactUser", function(request, response) {

// Get parameters
var userID       = request.params.userID; // I'm obviously passing this parameter in the method call


// Query
/* ------ query = Any of the above options ------ */


Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data: {
        title   : "New message",
        alert   : "User message",   
        badge   : "Increment",
        sound   : "soundNotifUserContact.caf",
        "params" : {
            "pushType"  : 2,
            "userID"    : userID
        }
    }
}, {
    success: function() {
        response.success();
    },
    error: function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    }
    });

});
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: how u call cloud method from android ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works well for me, but you have to link your users with your installations before:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo('username', 'Sento');
// Find devices associated with these users
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
// need to have users linked to installations
pushQuery.matchesQuery('user', query);


Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
        aps: {
            alert: "Test",
            sound: ""
        }
    }
}, {
    success: function () {
        response.success("Hello world!");
    },
    error: function (error) {
        response.error(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: I added a pointer to User.installation and the link seems fine. I'm able to click on the installation and the installation were displayed. But still unable to send it.

Comment: Yes! Bless your heart for this.

Comment: Was trying to this and wrote the same code, but I cannot understand how do you link User and Installation? Should I do this from client side or is there a way to do it from Parse dashboard?

Comment: First you have to create a column as a pointer to installation in your user table (dashboard). Once the users register with your app you have to update the user table with the installation you will get from Parse (client side).

Comment: Help! After trying your code it is giving me this..
error 102: bad type for $inQuery parse.com/api/collections/collection.go:389 inQueryVisitor.runChildQuery parse.com/api/collections/collection.go:363 inQueryVisitor.Visit <autogenerated>:171 (*inQueryVisitor).Visit parse.com/api/types/query/visitor.go:27 Visit parse.com/api/collections/collection.go:403 (*Collection).resolveInQueries parse.com/api/collections/collection.go:550 (*Collection).PrepareQuery parse.com/api/collections/installation_collection.go:740 (*InstallationCollection).Iterate parse.com/push/expansion/expansion_job.go:362

Comment: Now i am having an another problem ... iam sending the notification from parse its updating the record to installation table but didnt get the notification to that device.. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can join Parse.Session and Parse.Installation with a user pointer as the Session primary key, next "installationId" as the join key.

```
var PushSend = function(payload, dbContact) {
    var querySession = new Parse.Query(Parse.Session);
        querySession.equalTo("user", dbContact);
        querySession.descending("updatedAt");

querySession.first({ useMasterKey: true })

.then(function(dbSession) {
    var installId = dbSession.get("installationId");

    var installQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        installQuery.equalTo("installationId", installId);

        Parse.Push.send( {
            where: installQuery,
            data: {
                alert: payload
            }
        }, { useMasterKey: true} )

        .then(function() {
            // "success"
        }, function(error) {
            // "failed"
        } );
    }, function(error) {
        // "failed"
    } );
}
```

The above cloud function takes as arguments :

1. the payload text string
2. a destination contact pointer (you have for example previously queried from Parse.User)

Answer (score -2):

I am using the first of the two methods that you mentioned, and it works fine.

Just make sure that you use objectId and not the username for `targetUser.id`.

Ex:

```
targetUser.id = 'Qhao1j22j';   //Never hard code like this though.
```