# Parse Sending push notification to specific user from Cloud code

Tags: javascript, android, ios, parse-platform

I want to send a push notification from parse cloud code to a specific user.
So i have created a user section in installation class of my parse table and i save the user object id there so i can target the user by id and send push from cloud code.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dvedyza4bz3z00j/userObjec.PNG?dl=0

From parse.com it is very simple to do, i did it like this with condition
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mb3pb2izb0jlj9/pushs.PNG?dl=0

But what i want to do is to send a push notification when a user adds new object in the class my class is "Ticket".

This class has ACL enabled. 
What i want to do is very simple send push to the user which created the object through cloud code

Here is my cloud code

```
  Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Ticket", function(request) {
  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);

  Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQuery,
        data: {
            alert: "New Ticket Added",
            sound: "default"
              }
        },{
        success: function(){
           response.success('true');
        },
        error: function (error) {
           response.error(error);
        }
      });
});
```

This code sends push to all users.

Please help

Comment: Hey Beri, have you checked out this similar post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040437/parse-cloud-send-push-to-a-single-user?rq=1

Answer (score 10):

**This can be a solution:**

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave( "Ticket", function(request) {

                 //Get value from Ticket Object
                  var username = request.object.get("username");

                  //Set push query
                  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
                  pushQuery.equalTo("username",username);

                  //Send Push message
                  Parse.Push.send({
                                  where: pushQuery,
                                  data: {
                                  alert: "New Ticket Added",
                                  sound: "default"
                                  }
                                  },{
                                  success: function(){
                                  response.success('true');
                                  },
                                  error: function (error) {
                                  response.error(error);
                                  }
                 });




});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a filter to the pushQuery for the user created the object.