# Parse and Swift: How use advance targeting push to specific devices without users?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I currently creating an app where the users can add a posting without logging into the app or using any credentials.

Other users of the app can open the app and directly comment on the posts(the comments are an array of the post object).

I read the parse docs and I believe that this will use advance targeting. I saw `PFInstallation.currentInstallation()` for advanced targeting but I believe that is based on the users class and I am not using the Parse.com users class

**What I would like to do is to send a push notification to the original poster when a comment is added to their post...** So, I was wondering how I would go completing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It couldn't be easier,

Installation has a "user" column.  Just make a query that matches the "user" of interest.  So, your code will look something like this....

```
if ( .. comment made, need to send a push .. ) 
    {
    console.log(">>> 'comment' was added....");
    
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.equalTo('user', .. whoWroteThePost .. );
    alert = "Wow! You have a new comment on a post you wrote!!!";
    Parse.Push.send(
        {
        where:query,
        data:{ alert: alert, badge: "Increment" }
        });
    return;
    }
```

Note that you said ...

**"What I would like to do is to send a push notification to the original poster when a comment is added to their post... "**

In that sentence you speak of the "original poster".  So, that's going to be a variable like originalPoster.  So this line of code

```
    query.equalTo('user', .. whoWroteThePost .. );
```

will be

```
    query.equalTo('user', originalPoster );
```

Note that this is extremely common, and you can find endless examples on the web!  Here's just one: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29387917/294884)

Note that:

## Parse's term "advanced targeting" is very confusing.

To phrase the same thought another way,

## Parse's 'channels' are just silly, ignore them.

That is to say, simply ignore the "channels" nonsense, and just search on users. It's easier and less confusing than the channels business, which is just an extra field you have to fill-out al the time.

It's just one of those weird things about Parse.

I've never used the "non-advanced targeting" - it's stupid and pointless. And the "advanced" targeting is trivial to use: assuming you can write cloud code at all you can do "advanced" targeting. If you can write a query in cloud code, you can do "advanced" targeting.

Essentially,

```
    query.equalTo('user', .. whoWroteThePost .. );
```

Note that, of course, you may have to first look up who wrote the post, and then from there you can make the query for the Push.

Note, in this process it makes:

## no difference at all if the user is anonymous.

You can and should go ahead and send pushes, in the same way.

Comment: So this will work when I create a PFUser? Match the installation to the PFUser? Because as of now I don't have any type of users.

Comment: Hi RS, as a new user, be sure to "thumb up" and "tick" any useful answers, so you get points, and can thus ask more questions.  Yes, this works with PFUser, that is just what I am talking about.  I have given all the code.  I will edit-in a couple more lines of explanation to help.

Comment: Hi RS, is there something more you need on this?  As a new user you need to "thumb up" and "tick" answers that are useful.

Comment: Hi joe, thanks for the answer, I am trying out your method but am having some trouble implementing anonymous users to match the installation. Every time the app is opened a new anonymous user is created.

Comment: If so, you are doing something totally wrong with the user handling.  You need to ask a **new question** which says **each time I open, I get a new anonymous user in the name of all that is holy can someone help me with this problem**

Comment: don't hesitate to link to your new question, from here, so people can continue helping!

Comment: Hi Joe, just figured it out... Will attach a link for a question that I found. Thanks for the help though. I will try out your method of sending a push notifications to the user as soon as I get the posts and comments connected to the anonymous users. I will definitely let you know if I have any problems... Once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Here is the code for anyone that needs help creating an anonymous user... From parse's documentation `var user = PFUser.currentUser()

        PFAnonymousUtils.logInWithBlock {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil || user == nil {
                println("Anonymous login failed.")
            } else {
                println("Anonymous user logged in.")
            }
        }
        
        user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool, signupError: NSError?) -> Void in
            if signupError == nil {
        }
        } `

Comment: Here's the link to my problem(I wasn't saving the user)... https://parse.com/questions/creating-a-user-without-a-username-or-password.

Comment: Hi Joe, I had a question about the code that you posted above `if ( .. comment made, need to send a push .. )`... Is it possible to have a conditional statement `if (query.whereKey("commentNumber", greaterThan: (0)){` send a notification? I am having trouble formatting the code to send a push after that commentNumber column increases because it says "cannot invoke wherekey with an argument list of type".

Comment: HI RS, sure, the thing to do is make a new question; you'll have to show all your code in question.   Keep the question itself as short as possible and point to exactly where the problem arises.  Be sure to totally format your code in the question. Don't hesitate to leave a link here to your new question.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced targeting is not done against users. It's just that is the easiest way to show an example.

You need to store the installation against the objects you want to push to. So in this case store the installation against the post. Then when the comment comes in you can send a notification to the installation connected to the post it relates to.

Comment: Do you know how that would look in code with a pfobject? Sorry, I am having trouble trying to figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking something called anonymous users. There is almost impossible to send notification without user's data. But, Parse.com provides something called anonymous users so that app users are not necessary to sign up in order to fully function something user related operations.

Then, you will need to store some information in order to find the target.

[Parse.com Anonymous Users](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-anonymous-users)