# Parse Server Push Notification to Specific user issue

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

I need to send a Push notification after a class is updated by the user, the push notification is working from the Dashboard.
I added this code to my Cloud Code, i can see the logs with the success message, but the notification is not being sent to the user, on the past notification, it shows that was sent, but the audience is Everyone, but pushs sent is 0, this is my Cloud Code

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Class", function(request, response) {
var inObject = request.object;
if (inObject.get("isLost")){
    console.log("inObject is lost");

    var targetUser = new Parse.User();
    targetUser.id = inObject.get("UserID");

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.equalTo("user", targetUser);

    Parse.Push.send({
        where: query,
        data: {
            alert: "InObject",
            badge: "Increment",
            message: "Testando"
        }
    }, {
        success: function() {
            // Push was successful
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            // Handle error
            console.log("error: "+error.code+" message "+error.message);
            throw "Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
        },
        useMasterKey: true
    });
}
```

});

I tried to do the double query as the post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040437/parse-cloud-send-push-to-a-single-user), but no success, i loged the user ID and is the same as show on my Installation in the Dashboard.
If i click the Push notification for more details this is the Target that it shows:
[Target details from push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnCQv.png)

**Edit**

Save code for that class(it's in java):

```
ParseObject object = new ParseObject(Class.class.getSimpleName());
    object.put(NAME, getName());
    object.put(UUID, getUUID());
    object.put(ICON_ID, getIconID());
    object.put(ADDRESS, getAddress());
    object.put(ID1, iD1.toString());
    object.put(ID2, iD2.toString());
    object.put(ID3, iD3.toString());
    object.put(IS_LOST, getIsLost());
    object.put(USER, parseUserID);
    object.put(DISTANCE, getDistance());
    object.put(LATITUDE, getLatitude());
    object.put(LONGITUDE, getLongitude());
    object.saveEventually();
```

The parseID is being generated by the ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectID();

Comment: Your query is returning 0 installations, so 0 pushes are sent! Use this: `var user = request.object.get("user");`

Comment: @SteveMcMeen, this way it works, but which user is being passed? the one that made the request? If yes, then this won't work for me, as i need the user that is saved on the inObject.

Comment: Yes, that user is the one who made the request, please add the code for saving that class so I can help you better, I don't know what sort of data you are saving.

Comment: @SteveMcMeen added the code for the save, on Parse Dashboard the UserId is saved as a String

Comment: You are setting USER and trying to fetch UserID

Answer (score 0):

So, after trying this in a lot of ways, i ended up creating a relation between my object and the ParseUser object, this solved the issue, still i don't know why can't i just save the UserID, but my problem is solved now.